# Worklight 5.0.5.1 && Protecting applications

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working with the sample  "Module_21_-_Form_Based_Authentication"(available on [IBM getting started Website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html))

In this Sample the protection is on the Adapter ( DummyAdapter.xml)

```
<procedure name="getSecretData" securityTest="DummyAdapter-securityTest"/>
```

I would like to put the protection on the Application. In order  to do that, I had this following line into the application-descriptor.xml

```
<common securityTest="DummyAdapter-securityTest"/>
```

**With Worklight v5.0.5 evrything works perfectly BUT  with Worklight v5.0.5.1 I have an issue** . The login form isn't shown properly (opacity ) and the "Loading" is still visible.

```
<div id="WLbusyContainer">
     <div id="WLbusyOverlay"></div>
      <div id="WLbusy" style="left: 695.5px; top: 218px;">
     <h1 id="WLbusyTitle">Loading</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried with different environment securityTest => Same issue

Answer (score 0):

The opacity, in fact an overlay on the application, is shown when the busy indicator ("Loading...") is displayed. In v5.0.5.1 there are some unfortunate bugs with the busy indicator. Fixes are coming in the imminently released v5.0.6, which also address this problem of an always-shown busy indicator.

As a workaround in the meanwhile you can set connectOnStartup to "false" in yourApplication\common\js\initOptions.js

Alternatively, you can keep connectOnStartup with "true", and try the following in wlCommonInit:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   WL.Client.__hideBusy();
}, 500);
```

Comment: **connectOnStartup to "false"** : The "Authentification" form isn't displayed on start up. The application isn't protected

Comment: **connectOnStartup with "true" and update wlCommonInit** : wlCommonInit isn't called on start up . If I call it, It works **but the same issue occurs on the log out**